# Using PHP Redis client, create new $connection object in each PHP script in application, or create one GLOBAL $connection object?

Tags: php, redis, predis

In my PHP application, I am trying to use Redis (rather Predis, the PHP client for Redis) for data caching, and for that I am following [this tutorial.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-redis-in-php)

Now I will need to store data in the cache in one PHP script/page. For that I will create a Predis client object **`$redis`** and then use this `$redis` object to call its functions like **`set()`** and **`expire()`** on it to store the data as key value pairs. An example snippet is given below.

Now the problem is that, *in another PHP script/page*, I will need to read the data stored in the cache. For that, I will need to call the functions like **`get()`** or **`exists()`** *on the `$redis` object again.*

Now my question is that in this second PHP script/page, should I create a new Predis client object like the `$redis` mentioned above (then I'll need to create a new $redis object every time I want to access data stored in cache in a new PHP script/page), or should I declare the first one as **`GLOBAL`**, so that it is accessible from all PHP scripts/pages in my web application? What is the correct practice

***Example PHP first script:***

```
<?php
require "predis/autoload.php";
PredisAutoloader::register();
try {
    $redis = new PredisClient();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
// sets message to contian "Hello world"
$redis->set('message', 'Hello world');
?>
```

***Example PHP Second Script:***

```
<?php
/* THE FOLLOWING PART WHICH CREATES A $redis 
OBJECT SEEMS TO BE AN OVERDO. SHOULDN'T WE BE 
USING THE SAME $redis OBJECT FROM THE ABOVE SNIPPET? */


require "predis/autoload.php";
PredisAutoloader::register();
try {
    $redis = new PredisClient();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

// gets the value of message
$value = $redis->get('message');
?>
```

Comment: Create one instance and pass it around to your different classes using [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: <!-- is not a PHP comment.

Comment: @ryantxr My mistake. Corrected!

Comment: GLOBAL won't work in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

The answer really depends on the complexity of your web application. One simple way to do this that you can implement easily is to make a singleton class and use a static variable in that class.

```
class MyRedis {
    private static $redis;
    static function shared() {
        if ( empty(self::$redis) ) {
            try {
                self::$redis = new PredisClient();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return self::$redis;
    }
}
```

Now when you want your object you do this:

```
$myRedisObject = MyRedis::shared();
// or 
$message = MyRedis::shared()->get('message');
```

It will make one if it has not done so already.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to do this - you could run some tests to check but according to the [Predis docs](https://github.com/nrk/predis):

> Connections to Redis are lazy meaning that the client connects to a
>   server only if and when needed. While it is recommended to let the
>   client do its own stuff under the hood, there may be times when it is
>   still desired to have control of when the connection is opened or
>   closed: this can easily be achieved by invoking $client->connect() and
>   $client->disconnect().

It also depends how many connections you are making -- it could be a case of over-engineering as the connection overhead, while real, is pretty low.

I also assume in your example both scripts are being included in one request. You could have some kind of messaging/cache component that stores the data in Redis as well as makes it available to the local script environment, just depends on the specifics of your data requirements.